Edit page for multiple image upload with preview
I am working on a product posting page, which supports up to 5 images. I set the 5 images limit with data-max_length="5".
For the Add Page, I use the following:
HTML:
<div class="upload__box">
  <div class="upload__btn-box">
    <label class="upload__btn">
      <p>Upload images</p>
      <input type="file" multiple="" data-max_length="5" class="upload__inputfile">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="upload__img-wrap"></div>
</div>

CSS:
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.upload {
  &__box {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  &__inputfile {
    width: .1px;
    height: .1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  &__btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 116px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid;
    background-color: #4045ba;
    border-color: #4045ba;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
    
    &:hover {
      background-color: unset;
      color: #4045ba;
      transition: all .3s ease;
    }
    
    &-box {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
  
  &__img {
    &-wrap {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin: 0 -10px;
    }
    
    &-box {
      width: 200px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    &-close {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 24px;
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;

        &:after {
          content: '\2716';
          font-size: 14px;
          color: white;
        }
      }
  }
}

.img-bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

JavaScript:
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  ImgUpload();
});

function ImgUpload() {
  var imgWrap = "";
  var imgArray = [];

  $('.upload__inputfile').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', function (e) {
      imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');

      var files = e.target.files;
      var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
      var iterator = 0;
      filesArr.forEach(function (f, index) {

        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          return;
        }

        if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
          return false
        } else {
          var len = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
              len++;
            }
          }
          if (len > maxLength) {
            return false;
          } else {
            imgArray.push(f);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
              var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>";
              imgWrap.append(html);
              iterator++;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', ".upload__img-close", function (e) {
    var file = $(this).parent().data("file");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      if (imgArray[i].name === file) {
        imgArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
}

The Add Page works pretty well.
However, after a product is added and the images are uploaded, for the Edit Page, I have a problem.
I use the following code to show the uploaded images' preview.
HTML and PHP:
<?php if($row_item["image_1"] != '') { ?>
    <div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(./images/<?= $row_item["image_1"] ?>)' data-number='1' data-file='' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($row_item["image_2"] != '') { ?>
    <div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(./images/<?= $row_item["image_2"] ?>)' data-number='2' data-file='' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($row_item["image_3"] != '') { ?>
    <div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(./images/<?= $row_item["image_3"] ?>)' data-number='3' data-file='' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($row_item["image_4"] != '') { ?>
    <div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(./images/<?= $row_item["image_4"] ?>)' data-number='4' data-file='' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($row_item["image_5"] != '') { ?>
    <div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(./images/<?= $row_item["image_5"] ?>)' data-number='5' data-file='' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>
<?php } ?>

The problem now is, in the Edit Page, the 5 images limit doesn't work properly.
For example, let's say in the Add Page, the user uploaded 2 images. Now, in the Edit Page, the user should only be able to add a maximum of 3 images only. But this doesn't work.
Also, if the user removed an image, then the user should be allowed to add an additional 4 images.
Please help me, how can I make the Edit Page work?

The JavaScript doesn't know that there are existing images, so it looks like you'll need to count them upon page load (or store that value in another data attribute).

Yes, I am aware of that. Also, if an existing image or images is/are removed, then we will need to increase the maxLength accordingly too. Any idea how we can do this?

I would count them up in PHP and output the value in an HTML data attribute, then grab that value with JavaScript. Alternatively, you could count the existing "upload__img-box" elements in JavaScript.
